# how to access a function of one controller from another in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how can i access a function of one controller from another controller.

Here are two controllers, monthlyOptionsController and yearlyController.

```
myapp.controller("monthlyOptionsController", ['$scope','$injector', function($scope){

    $scope.initializeMonthlyCell   =   function(monthh){
    }
}]);

myapp.controller("yearlyController", ['$scope','$injector', function($scope){

    $scope.yearlyFunc   =   function(monthh){
         //here i want to access initializeMonthlyCell function 
         // like this initializeMonthlyCell(monthNumber);
    }
}]);
```

In yearlyFunc function  i want to access initializeMonthlyCell function/
how can i do this. may be this repeat question.but anyone tell me how i can do this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 approaches:

- Create your initializeMonthlyCell in a service and inject it into your controllers to reuse.
- Use $on, $emit, $broadcast to communicate between controllers scopes.

Example code with the first approach (it's more recommended in your case)

```
myapp.factory("dateService",function(){
       return {
             initializeMonthlyCell : function (month){

            }
        };
    });

    myapp.controller("monthlyOptionsController", ['dateService','$scope','$injector', function(dateService,$scope){

        $scope.initializeMonthlyCell   =   function(month){
           return dateService.initializeMonthlyCell(month);
        }
    }]);

    myapp.controller("yearlyController", ['dateService','$scope','$injector', function(dateService,$scope){

        $scope.yearlyFunc   =   function(monthh){
             // call dateService.initializeMonthlyCell
        }
    }]);
```

Comment: Khanh TO can you explain with my code.because i am new in angularJS

Comment: @priyashivale: I updated my answer. The second approach is another way to communicate between scopes. It's possible but not recommended in your case because you have to communicate back the result to `yearlyController` (unnecesarily complex). I did not include a code for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to write a service to be injected in both controllers in order to share data.

```
myapp.service('Monthly', function() {
   return {
      initializeMonthlyCell: function(month) {
         return month;
      }
   }
});

myapp.controller("monthlyOptionsController", function($scope) { 

});

myapp.controller("yearlyController", function($scope, Monthly) {
   $scope.yearlyFunc   =   function(monthh){
     return Monthly.initializeMonthlyCell(monthh);
   }
});
```